# arduino bluetooth rc car using case switch statment

Tags: arduino

I build a bluetooth controled car that i have some problem with the code to it. Im using a switch case Statements to control it from my phone. The code works fine but i got a problem with the default: i want it to stop the car if it doesn't receive anything via the bluetooth. My code doesent seem to execute the default: at all. and i dont know whats the problem.

well here is my code.

```
int IN1 = 7;
int IN2 = 5;
int IN3 = 4;
int IN4 = 2;

int inByte = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
   //read my bluetooth
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(inByte);

    switch (inByte) {
      case 'i':
        Serial.println("forward");
        digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
        break;
      case 'j':
        Serial.println("left");
        digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
        break;
      case 'l':
        Serial.println("right");
        digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
        break;
      case 'k':
        Serial.println("reverse");
        digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
        break;

      default:
          Serial.println("stop");
          digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your car is receiving nothing, your switch-case statement never gets called (Serial.Available() is false). So you can't reach the default this way.

Comment: Ok.Do you got any ideas on how i can fix it??

Comment: Try to use a timer and check if a long time nothing received. Loook here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer